client_is_modern return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9' TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

{
"error": "Input nbnb.csv of type: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'> is not
supported." }
if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 358, in
client_is_modern
return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9' TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable


tried spliting that code but still its not working

Can you share more of your code so that we can easier debug, thank you.
